# High Performance Counters in Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, google-cloud-spanner

I'm looking to keep running counts of some items such as likes and comments on a post. The write rate can be high, e.g. 1K likes/sec.

Using a `SELECT COUNT` does not seem feasible even if the result set is indexed as there could be a few million rows to count.

I'm thinking of using a sharded counters approach where a specific counter (likes for a given post) consists of `N` shards/rows. Incrementing the counter would increment the column value of one shard's row, while reading the counter would read all shard rows and sum the count values. Would there be any issues in such an approach with Spanner?

I understand that in Bigtable, multiple updates to the same row will create new versions of cells in the row and as a result, you can cause a row to exceed its size limit. So using rows as sharded counters in Bigtable seems to be a bad idea. Does Spanner have any similar issues?

Comment: For the Bigtable side of things you probably won't have row size concerns as long as you have a sensible [GC Policies](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/managing-tables#gc-policies) in place, and you could ensure atomic writes via [ReadModifyWrite Increment](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable#ReadModifyWrite.Increment) operations.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that in Bigtable, multiple updates to the same row will
>   create new versions of cells in the row and as a result, you can cause
>   a row to exceed its size limit. So using rows as sharded counters in
>   Bigtable seems to be a bad idea. Does Spanner have any similar issues?

As noted in the comments, you could use the ReadModifyWrite Increment API, with the caveat that row-transactional operations like ReadModifyWrite in Bigtable are slower.

However, using multiple rows to represent a single counter and then reading the rows together using a prefix scan should be fine.

The key would be to [use arbitrary prefixes on the row key](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#ensure_that_your_row_key_avoids_hotspotting) to distribute writes across the nodes in your cluster and avoid hotspotting.

Answer (score 2):

Sharding the counters to improve parallelism seems like a good idea. Cloud Spanner manages the older versions of the data in a different way than BigTable, so you may not hit the same limits. Spanner keeps old versions around for 1 hour. However you may want to take care in designing your schema to [avoid hotspots](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design#choose_a_primary_key_to_prevent_hotspots).

I would recommend though that you try to implement a memory caching layer on top of Spanner. This could be used to:

1. Batch some updates together.
2. Do fast reads/counts.

There will be some tradeoffs in possibly losing some updates if the cache goes away, but that may be acceptable if it is just caching likes/counts.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, we plan to have a Redis caching layer to provide fast reads/counts. We've considered batching writes as well, though it's more of a product decision for us.